# Как заполнить поле с помощью url-js?

Tags: javascript

Есть поле, туда вводишь цифры и если перейти по url-js ссылке эта форма отправится на сервер, а как сделать так, чтобы я перешла по url-js  поле заполнилось как я хочу и отправило на сервер. тут - http://www.alfafreedesign.ru/metod-submit.html есть пример, но мне нужно чтобы переходя по url-js заполнялась форма, в примере не так

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, по ссылке самое непонятное описание общения клиент-сервер.
для отправки неких данных на сервер есть контейнер form. в параметре action которго указывается путь к скрипту, который обработает данные.
допустим у вас есть 
`<form action=test.php method=post>
<input type=text name='NAME1' value="" />
<input type='submit' />`

если вы нажмете кнопку, то данные из поля input отправятся в test.php, где будут обработаны: в $_POST['NAME1'] будет какое-то значение.
если же вам надо обработать данные до отправки на сервер, то пишите: `<form action=test.php method=post onSubmit='return SubmitFunc()'>`, где SubmitFunc() - функция, которая выполнит некоторые действия перед отправкой и после перейдет к скрипту  test.php, либо вернет `false` и выполнение прервется.

`SubmitFunc()` можно описать в отдельном файле или в тегах `<script></script>`

Comment: Нееет, мне нужна ссылка(url-javascript) чтобы я перешла на нее и данные из формы отправились. Допустим форма для заполнения будет доступна через минуту, а я уже ввела в url-javascript'e и ждала истечения таймера. Типо такого - HREF="javascript:document.s.submit(); но эта url-javascript не заполняет формы, что нужно сюда добавить чтобы при переходе по url-js заполнялись формы?

Comment: сначала кое-что поясню из примера по ссылке. по умолчанию данные на сервер отправляются кнопкой `<input type=submit/>`. Кроме того отправить данные можно графической кнопкой `<input type=image />`  или вызвав функцию submit() для произвольной формы на странице. в параметре action указывается скрипт, которому будут переданые данные. в случае в примере данные не обрабатываются, а просто выводится сообщение. 

в вашем примере попробуйте с такими изменениями:

... ACTION="javascript:window.alert(document.getElementById('ID1').value);void(0);"
...
 <INPUT SIZE=1 MAXLENGTH=1 id=ID1>
...

Comment: а если вам надо передать данные на другую страницу, тогда по ссылке вызовите стороннюю функцию, которая обработает данные, запакует в ссылку вида `next-page.htm?var1=value1&var2=value2....` и перейдет по ней. на странице next-page.htm, в обработчике onLoad страницы вам придется разобрать URL, и заполнить поля формы данными из нее